# Calling SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait in a loop

Tags: java, swing, plot, synchronization

I am trying to save .PNG image of a `JFrame`. In `JFrame`, I have two Plot3DPanel objects. Most likely because of synchronization fault, left-size frame is invisible while saving .PNG.

[image]

Therefore, I use the following code:

```
try
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new VisualSerializer(P[i], Q[i], folder + "C" + i).run();
        }
    });

    serialize(P[i], folder + "P" + i);
    serialize(Q[i], folder + "P" + i);

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But now, I get compile error

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined
>   in a different method

however, I need my filenames to be different. Also, I need to iterate through my array of objects. What can I do to prevent this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make final copies of any variable that needs to be passed into the anonymous inner class, for instance if `i` is the problem:

```
final int index = i;
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new VisualSerializer(P[index], Q[index], folder + "C" + index).run();
    }
});
```

Another solution is to use class fields inside of the anonymous inner class.

Comment: No compile errors! But I get blank .PNG images now.

Comment: @cagirici: your new problem is one that is completely different and involves code not shown. I suggest that you ask a new question on this site for this, showing more code and explaining more about the relevant issues. Note that it frightens me to see `run()` called as that suggests to me that someone might be trying background threading by calling a Runnable's `run()` method directly -- which is not how threading works. Also, should VisualSErializer be called on the EDT?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Declare a new final variable, initialize it to the variable you want, then use the copy as Hovercraft Full Of Eels said
2. Make your variable a field variable. Field variables do not need to be final in order to be used within an anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution from OP.*

**Found the mistake!**
Here is correct modification:

```
final int index = i;
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait
(
       new VisualSerializer(P[index], Q[index], folder + "C" + index)
);
```

a new `Runnable` is redundant. The class is already type of `Runnable`.